# set active tabs using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have set of three Html tabs like this :

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="tabCtrl">         
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" ng-click="toggle_over1()" href="#!home/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" ng-click="toggle_over2()"  href="#!/underwriting">Underwriting</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" ng-click="toggle_over3()" href="#!operations/">Operations</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

when ever I click on the tab it should get active. I am trying to implement it using angularjs. I tried to implement it in so many ways, but I couldn't achieve it. Please let me know, if there is any better.

AngularJS :

```
app.controller('tabCtrl',function($scope) {
$scope.toggle_over = function(id) {
    // implementation part
    }
});
```

Comment: Use `ng-class` or `ng-style`. Add active class after clicked on tabs.

Comment: you call `toggle_over1()` instead of `toggle_over(1)` and also with the other two links? Guess that's a typo in your question?

Comment: if you have any demo sample , please drop it @KaustubhKhare

Comment: @SRK check [Example of ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle#examples).

Comment: sure @KaustubhKhare

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(1)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(1)">Home</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(2)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(2)">Underwriting</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(3)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(3)">Operations</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div ng-show="tab.isSet(1)"><h4>Home</h4></div>
        <div ng-show="tab.isSet(2)"><h4>Underwriting</h4></div>
        <div ng-show="tab.isSet(3)"> <h4>Operations</h4></div>


    $scope.tab = 1;

    $scope.setTab = function (tabId) {
        this.tab = tabId;
    };

    $scope.isSet = function (tabId) {
        return this.tab === tabId;
    };
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fwoxdjsu/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/15753/) using angular 1.3, any version will works the example is simple, only using the view and ng-class

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="tabCtrl">         
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
          <li class="nav-item" ng-class="{'active': active===1}">
            <a class="nav-link active" ng-click="active=1;" href="#!home/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" ng-class="{'active': active===2}">
            <a class="nav-link active" ng-click="active=2"  href="#!/underwriting">Underwriting</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" ng-class="{'active': active===3}">
            <a class="nav-link active" ng-click="active=3" href="#!operations/">Operations</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```